# Routing in Polymer Starter Kit

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-starter-kit

I am running Polymer Starter Kit. If I click Contact on the menu, then click Users, I am being redirected to Users page successfully. However, if I click Contact, then enter http://localhost:5000/#!/users in the location bar manually, I am not redirected and get error message: `Can't find http://localhost:5000/#!/users. Redirected you to Home Page`, even though the same location is set after clicking on Users through the menu. Why is that so?

Comment: In the router try 2 expressions covering "/users"   and  another route without slash ie just "users"

Answer (score 0):

It's because your JavaScript hasn't had a chance to load.  When you click on a hashbang link the JavaScript has loaded and it will route appropriately

Comment: But showing the message is done by page.js route, so it managed to load.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problem with you, but im just trying to add

```
<base href="/">
```

at a first line below a tags `<head>`. And it works for me when im trying to direct access the page.